# ReactJS Submit form with default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

A component has a FormControl (react-bootstrap) which could have a defaultValue defined.

The idea is that: When that default value is defined, the form submits.

I have tried defining the componentDidMount() function, but it loops infinitely (renders - submits - render ...)

Edit:
I'm not allowed to share production code (Company policy). Instead, I made a snippet to try to explain the situation:

```
export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // This was my first approach.
        // Which did not work since after submitting
        // the component re-renders, submits and so on...
        if (this.props.defaultValue) {
            document.getElementById('formName').submit();
        }
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // doSomethingWithFormData(event);
    }

    render() {
        <Form inline onSubmit={(ev) => this.handleFormSubmit(ev)} id='formName'>
            <FormGroup controlId="ValueFormGroup">
                <FormControl
                    type="text"
                    id="formName"
                    name="fieldName"
                    required={true}
                    defaultValue={this.state.value}
                />
                &nbsp;
                <Button 
                    type="submit"
                    bsStyle="primary"
                </Button>
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    }
}
```

A value for the FormControl `defaultValue` could be received via GET parameters (http://url.com/something?value=aValue).
If such a value is received, the form's input will be filled and the form submitted. Then a REST service will be asked for the results and finally, when they arrive, fill a table below the form. All of that is done by `handleFormSubmit()`.

After the form has been submitted, the page keeps reloading indefinitely.

Comment: Please provide code you've written to show what you've done, and so any problems can be found.

Comment: Maybe you are calling some function that is gone crazy :| Anyway, without code we can't help you much, please share so we can take a look.

Comment: Thank you both. I have found a solution I posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I'm writing the details below, in case somebody finds them useful:
To fix the problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.defaultValue) {
        const event = new Event('submit', {cancelable: true});
        document.getElementById('formName').dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The `{cancelable: true}` is the most important thing there, since for [event.preventDefault();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to work (prevent the page to be reloaded), the event has to be [cancellable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable).

I'm not an expert in react so I'm open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `submit()` on the DOM element, you can just call `doSomethingWithFormData` directly from `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.defaultValue) {
    doSomethingWithFormData(this.props.defaultValue)
  }
}
```

This wont trigger a form submission or page reload.